# выбор элемента из СКРИПТА js

Tags: javascript, веб-скрейпинг

```
            <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new TradingView.widget({
        "autosize": true,
        "symbol": "OANDA:USDJPY",
        "interval": "1",
        "timezone": "exchange",
        "theme": "White",
        "style": "1",
        "locale": "en",
        "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "enable_publishing": false,
        "withdateranges": true,
        "hideideas": true
    });
</script>
```

Есть такой код который рисует график торгов. Мне  нужно выбрать с него Элементы текущих позиций валюты. Но я их могу получить после того когда через инспектор найду элементы которые рисует график и только тогда я получаю доступ к самим Элементам в дереве HTML.

Как мне получить Элементы с разу после отрисовки графика на странице и не заходить в инспектор кода чтоб найти элемент для того чтоб потом его мог найти JS как дом элемент

Comment: может быть до этих элементов/информации можно добраться, используя значение, возвращаемое из `new TradingView.widget(...)`?

Comment: спасибо вам за идею я попробую.  Если что получиться я напишу